# Synaptic Package manager problem

Tags: package-management

I am trying to install ubiquity-frontend-gtk through Synaptic Package manager but getting following error. I even cant install through terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubiquity-frontend-gtk
returned with following error
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubiquity-frontend-gtk : Depends: ubiquity (= 2.12.14) but 2.12.16 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

sudo aptitude install ubiquity-frontend-gtk (did not work for metoo)
```

[image: a busy cat]

anybody help me plz

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f update` followed by `sudo apt-get -f upgrade` might solve your problem.

Comment: i tried but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from `http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124`. I've followed these directions from this very post a while back. It took me a bit to find it again.

`sudo apt-get update` to update you list of available upgrades.

`sudo apt-get autoclean` to remove any partially installed packages.

`sudo apt-get clean` to cleal the apt cache.

`sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove any unneeded dependencies.

`sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq broken-pakage` will remove any broken package that you find in error messages.